# How to set public variable value of service, while defining provide in Angular

Tags: angular

I have service called Test.

```
export abstract class TestService {
 public canTest: boolean;
 abstract TestVariable(...messages: any[]): boolean;
}
```

Then definition class

```
export class TestVarialbeService extends TestService {

            TestVariable(...messages: any[]): boolean {
               if(canTest)
                 return true
               else 
                 return false
             }
   }
```

I want to initialize the variable canTest in AppModule where i inject the service.

```
@NgModule({
providers: [{ provide: TestService , useClass: TestVarialbeService,  ..want to set **canTest** variable over here }]
})
export class AppModule { 
  constructor(private testService : TestService)
  {
    
  }
}
```

Comment: why not use the constructor?

Comment: @MikeS. Constructor is working but don't it possible to add in mentioned place?